# Is there any way to override ZF2 application.config.php directives locally?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working on a ZF2 project and my public/index.php file is like follows:

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
require 'init_autoloader.php';
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Application initialize process starts with using application.config.php and I know that ZF2 provides nice way to override module configurations locally via filenames like modulename.local.php but not for application.config.php file.

For example, in application.config.php, I have a module_listener_options key as follows:

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
    // ...
    ),

    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
         // ...
         ),

    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
     ),

     'config_cache_enabled' => TRUE,
     'config_cache_key' => 'configuration_cache',
     'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../data/cache'
// ...
)
```

So I want to disable config caching locally while working on a development environment but I want to turn it on in a production environment without need a post-deployment tricks (like writing custom git-hook / bash script etc..).

Also, I have a `APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT` `$_ENV` variable on all servers (dev, prod, test) I don't know what is the best approach to achieve this in ZF2.

I found the [Stephen Rees-Carter's article](https://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/zf2-config-caching-with-composer), yes workarounds this problem but i want to learn is there any other / more elegant solutions which doesn't depends on composer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just test your environment variable in your app config and set caching accordingly, eg.,

```
<?php
// application.config.php
$env = getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT');
$configCacheEnabled = ($env == 'production');

return array(
    //..

    'config_cache_enabled' => $configCacheEnabled,

    //..
);
```

Comment: i think this is most simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: Also Rob Allen wrote a blog article about same problem and similar approach http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/caching-your-zf2-merged-configuration/

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to include modules only on your development setup, with a local file override.
You can easily just remove the environment variable check if you wished to just override with the presence of the local config file.

**application.config.php**

```
$config = array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ZfcBase',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);

if(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') == 'development' && is_readable('config/autoload/application.config.local.php')){
    $localAppConfig = require 'config/autoload/application.config.local.php';
    $config = array_merge_recursive($config,$localAppConfig);
} 

return $config;
```

**config/application.config.local.php**

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'ZFTool'
    ),
    /**
     * Add any overrides to the new local config
     */
);
```

You can then just add overrides to your local file, which can be different for staging and production environments.

Comment: Wouldn't having this `application.config.local.php` file in the autoload directory mean that it gets merged twice into the config?

Comment: why would it be merged twice? it will be loaded once, AFTER application.config.php is loaded, so values override the values inside application.config.php

Comment: You load it once manually from the `application.config.php`, but then because it ends in `local.php`, it will be matched by the `config_glob_paths` pattern and added to the config again (once all module configs have been merged). It may be better to name it something different, like `application.config.development.php` to avoid this side effect.

Comment: very good point, should probably change the file name, not a big issue just an oversight it won't cause any issues